# Is modern warfare 3 on the same engine that the last 2 were one?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

What engine is modern warfare 3 powered by and what other games have used this engine? Is it a very "modern" engine or is it a bit dated?

Comment: also if any non call of duty games use it....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modern Warefare 3 is running on the IW engine this engine was originally based off the Quake 3 engine created in 1999. This engine has gone through several different versions and has been used for several different games.

- Call of Duty 2 (2005) IW 2.0
- Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare (2007) IW 3.0
- Call of Duty: World at War (2008) Modified IW 3.0
- Quantum of Solace (2008) Heavly Modified IW 3.0
- Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2 (2009) IW 4.
- Call of Duty: Black Ops (2010) Modified IW 3.0
- GoldenEye 007 (2010) IW 3.0
- Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3 (2011) Version number is only listed as MW3. An [interview](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/hwkjy/iam_robert_bowling_creative_strategist_on_modern/c1yydex) with one of Infinity Wards creative strategists said that it is technically IW 5.0

As to whether it is dated or not is a bit of personal opinion. In my view it is pretty outdated these days.

Comment: now thats helpful!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is using the same engine that CoD 4 used, as well as CoDs 5 through 7.

Comment: Hey bumps, welcome to the site! Can you elaborate a bit on this? It would be nice to know what the engine specifically is called, as well as if you have any references for saying this.

Comment: yeah saying cod 5-7 doesnt help much at all